# Confusion over condition for zero current in potentiometer

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Given the below circuit for calculating emf of a battery(sorry about bad drawing), I did some calculations using Kirchoff's  1st and 2nd laws.
In loop 1 (cell E and ABC), we get $E-i_{1}R_{AB}-iR_{BC}=0$
In loop 2 (cell E and E1 and BC), we get $E-E_{1}-i_{2}r$
On equating, we get $i_{1}R_{AB}+iR_{BC}=E_{1}+i_{2}r$
Putting $i=i_{1}+i_{2}$ and simplifying we get, $$i_{1}(R_{AB}+R_{BC})+i_{2}(R_{BC}-R)=E_{1}$$
Hence we can say that $i_{2}=0$ would mean $i_1(R_{AB}+R_{BC})=E_{1} \implies$  Potential across AB = $E_{1}$
But what I don't understand is why the current is 0. So what if the potential difference across AB is $E_{1}$? Why would that stop the current from flowing through the lower branch?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the condition of null point of a potentiometer. 2 is not zero at every point but the point at which it is zero is specifically known as null point. I suggest you consider AC as 2 Resistors one between AB and the other between BC and then solve the question and not assume 2=0 until given in the question.

Comment: But the circuit in the explanation of how to find internal resistance of a battery using potentiometer clearly says i2=0! So how can I not assume that!

Comment: Then you should cite the article, or see if it says something of making i2=0 by adjusting B.

Comment: @Anili In order to find internal resistance a known resistance is connected across the battery and a new null point is obtained. Now, since it is a closed-loop Kirchoff's laws are valid and the current need not be zero

Comment: I would suggest you some videos for better understanding. 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X5beN3jTps 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkQIIvhuV-s